# Querying Facebook for details of a user's OAuth token

Tags: java, error-handling, serialization, facebook, oauth

This class exposes the public method `getAuthToken` which takes a user's Facebook OAuth token as an input parameter and queries Facebook for information about it - such as the application it is valid for, its expiry date, the user it belongs to etc.

The flow for this method is as follows:

- Uses the token passed into the method to construct a URL to be read from
- Reads the JSON response from Facebook into a String
- Deserializes this String into a new `FacebookAuthToken` object
- Returns this object

Once this object is returned it is possible to use the various public getter methods I have provided to query its attributes.

The main thing I don't like about this solution is that it uses two top-level classes - the `AuthTokenDeserializer` class as well as the primary `FacebookAuthToken` class. I tried to nest `AuthTokenDeserializer` within `FacebookAuthToken` but the compiler complained about trying to create a new `AuthTokenDeserializer` from within `getAuthToken`, which is a static context. Fair enough, I suppose.

Additionally I am not over the moon that `getAuthToken` throws an `IOException` - because now every invocation of this method within my application has to catch it. Perhaps it is better to catch this exception within the method and simply return `null`?

Apart from these issues, are there any other inefficiencies or elements of poor design in my code? I am new to Java so try to challenge everything I do (so that I get better).

```
class FacebookAuthToken {

    private static final String APP_ID = "99999999999999";

    // TODO: Refresh APP_TOKEN before Go-Live
    private static final String APP_TOKEN = "999999999999";

    private static final String URL_PLACEHOLDER =
            "https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=userToken&access_token=accessToken";

    private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN = APP_ID + "|" + APP_TOKEN;

    private String app_id;
    private String application;
    private int expires_at;
    private boolean is_valid;
    private int issued_at;
    private String[] scopes;
    private String user_id;

    public static FacebookAuthToken getAuthToken(String userToken) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL(buildAuthTokenURL(userToken));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        reader.close();
        String myJson = builder.toString();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(FacebookAuthToken.class,
                new AuthTokenDeserializer()).create();

        FacebookAuthToken authToken = gson.fromJson(myJson, FacebookAuthToken.class);

        return authToken;
    }

    public String getAppId() {
        return this.app_id;
    }

    public String getApp() {
        return this.application;
    }

    public int getExpiry() {
        return this.expires_at;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        return this.is_valid;
    }

    public int getCreated() {
        return this.issued_at;
    }

    public String[] getPermissions() {
        return this.scopes;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return this.user_id;
    }

    private static String buildAuthTokenURL(String userToken) {
        String result = URL_PLACEHOLDER.replaceAll("userToken", userToken);
        return result.replaceAll("accessToken", ACCESS_TOKEN);
    }
}
```

```
/* Example response to be deserialized by AuthTokenDeserializer:
{
   "data": {
      "app_id": "999999999999",
      "application": "MyApp",
      "expires_at": 1455462874,
      "is_valid": true,
      "issued_at": 1450278874,
      "scopes": [
         "public_profile"
      ],
      "user_id": "999999999999999"
   }
}
 */

class AuthTokenDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<FacebookAuthToken> {

    @Override
    public FacebookAuthToken deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type,
                                         JsonDeserializationContext context) {

        JsonElement data = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("data");
        return new Gson().fromJson(data, FacebookAuthToken.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These values would probably be better off in a configuration file or something - not embedded and compiled with the executable:

> ```
> private static final String APP_ID = "99999999999999";
>
> // TODO: Refresh APP_TOKEN before Go-Live
> private static final String APP_TOKEN = "999999999999";
>
> private static final String URL_PLACEHOLDER =
>         "https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=userToken&access_token=accessToken";
> ```

This means the `ACCESS_TOKEN` should probably be set in a dedicated method:

> ```
> private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN = APP_ID + "|" + APP_TOKEN;
> ```

I'd probably extract these app-config fields into their own app-config class, and have the `FacebookAuthToken` class take a dependency on it.

---

> *Additionally I am not over the moon that `getAuthToken` throws an `IOException` - because now every invocation of this method within my application has to catch it. Perhaps it is better to catch this exception within the method and simply return `null`?*

Absolutely! You'll want to perhaps log the exception details, but the client code only needs to care about whether or not they can get an authentication token.

Comment: Thanks Mat('s Mug). Is retuning `null` the standard way to signal to the client code that an error has occurred?

Answer (score 5):

#### Single responsibility principle

`FacebookAuthToken` does one too many things:

- download a URL
- create a token

It would be good to move the download logic to a separate method, a private helper.

#### Working with resources

Opening a reader and closing it manually is old fashioned and error prone. Use the modern try-with-resources syntax.